# How to display field label in Dropdown in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

[image]I need to display Lead labels in dropdown and account, contact and opportunity also in dropdown.

```
public class objectController
{
    public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    public String selectedObject {get; set;}

    public String selectedField {get; set;}

    Public objectController()
    {   
        selectedObject = 'account';
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectNames() 
    {
        List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
        entities.sort();
        for(String name : entities)
        {
            objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));
        }
        return objNames;
     }

     public List<SelectOption> getObjectFields() 
     {
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            List<SelectOption> fieldNames = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) 
            {  
                fieldNames.add(new SelectOption(fieldName,fieldName));
              //fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();//It provides to get the object fields label.
            }
            return fieldNames;
      }
```

vf page

```
<apex:page controller="objectController">
<apex:form > 
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                  <apex:outputlabel value="Object Names :"/> 
                      <apex:actionRegion >      
                          <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">                        
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Account" itemLabel="Account" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Contact" itemLabel="Contact"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Lead" itemLabel="Lead" />
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
</apex:selectList>
                     </apex:actionRegion>                         
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputlabel value="Field Names :"/>   
                      <apex:outputPanel id="myFields">   
                        <apex:actionRegion >  
                           <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectFields}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>      
                     </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: searching for the proper code and Im not getting the fields in dropdown so far

Comment: Im getting the api name and please refer the above code

Comment: I don't see any issues with the controller or markup. Is your problem that when you change the Object value, the related fields are not rendered?

Comment: You _have_ the correct information in `getObjectFields()`, where you're getting the label. Why aren't you using that in your SelectOptions?

Answer (score 1):

The field logic should be as follows, just need to use the commented code during the `selectOption` assignment.

```
public List<SelectOption> getObjectFields() {
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    List<SelectOption> fieldNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {  
        String label = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
        fieldNames.add(new SelectOption(fieldName,label));
    }
    return fieldNames;
}
```

It seems you have forgotten to update the form once the object value is updated. Two minor changes.

You need to add an `id` to your `form` and then use `<apex:actionSupport>` to `reRender` the page.

```
<apex:page controller="objectController">
    <apex:form id="form"> 
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputlabel value="Object Names :"/> 
                    <apex:actionRegion >      
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">                        
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Account" itemLabel="Account" />
                            ...
                            <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:actionRegion>                         
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                ...

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I want to display each object fields with label in dropdown in each column

Comment: Please find the above image FYI